# Optional ByVal boolean parameter is not taking its default value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am debugging a project right now and it has a function with the following signature:

```
Public Function changeRemoteDirectory(ByVal newDirectory As String, Optional ByVal Direction As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    MsgBox(direction)

    'rest of code

End Function
```

I was trying to figure out what was causing this function to return a value of `False` when I knew that it should return `True` given the input that I was supplying, so I put `MsgBox(direction)` into the `Function` to see what the value of `direction` was when I called the `Function`. I called the function like this, yet I received a `MsgBox` that showed the value of `direction` to be `False`:

```
changeRemoteDirectory("/internal")
```

The first parameter works just fine and the code that requires it to execute works correctly, but I cannot figure out why `Direction` has a value of `False` in a situation where, I believe, it should have its default value of `True`. I'm not totally opposed to rewriting the `Function` if need be, but can anybody here discern why `Direction` does not have a value of `True` when the function `changeRemoteDirectory()` is called without the second parameter supplied?

Comment: Use overloads instead. You get the same functionality without the debugging and performance problems.

Comment: @jbabey - Thank you. If I end up having to rewrite this function, that is exactly what I intend to do. Regardless, I'm still curious as to why this is happening because I've never had this issue pop up in my experience.

Comment: It sounds like you're experiencing one of many pains that optional parameters cause. When the code that calls `changeRemoteDirectory` is compiled, the optional parameter is injected into the calls just like a `const` would be replaced at compile time. Changes to the value of an optional parameter will not update without recompiling **the caller**. See [this article](http://jelle.druyts.net/2003/05/17/OptionalParametersVBNET.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @jbabey - Thanks for the great article. After reading it, I rebuilt the project and THEN started the Debugger, which resulted in the parameter storing the correct default value. Also, I'm going to follow that advice of yours and use overloads instead. If you put what you said in your comments into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're experiencing one of many pains that optional parameters cause.

When the code that calls `changeRemoteDirectory` is compiled, the optional parameter is injected into the calls just like a `const` would be replaced at compile time. Changes to the value of an optional parameter will not take effect without **recompiling the caller**.

See [this article](http://jelle.druyts.net/2003/05/17/OptionalParametersVBNET.aspx) for more info.

In general, you should use method overloads instead of optional parameters. You get all of the same functionality without the pain and performance drawbacks.